# How to over-ride system short-cut inside processing

Tags: java, macos, keyboard, keyboard-shortcuts, processing

How do I record a short-cut that is in use by the system with [Processing](https://processing.org)?

If I try to record `Apple-Key` + `Alt-key` + `Esc-key` (Which in OSX opens the force quit application window) the `Esc-key` never arrives at the `keyPressed` event.

Whilst pressing `Esc-key` by itself closes the window but still receiving the keyCode in [Processing](https://processing.org):

```
void keyPressed() {
    println(keyCode);
}
```

So my question is. How can I still receive the `Esc-key` when it fires a system event. Or even better over-ride system event all-together.

Comment: With core Processing and Java? This isn't going to happen. To do this you need code that can get close to the OS, which means JNI, JNA, or use of an OS-specific library.

Answer (score 0):

If I remember correctly, the quit on escape function runs after the keyPressed() event so you can do:

```
void keyPressed(){
  if(key==27){
    < insert code here >
    key=0;
  }
}
```

which will fool processing into thinking the escape key wasn't the key pressed.

The operating system keybinds on the other hand cannot be overriden (for example alt-f4 in windows force closes an application. This cannot be disabled as this is how you get out of a program that won't let you leave its interface). This is a security feature.

<------------------------------------------------------>

Sidenote: if you want to calculate multiple keys presses like your application quit example, a keyPressed event is fired for every push even if they are pressed at the exact same time, so you have to record what keys are pressed when keyPressed() is fired and record that they are no longer held when keyReleased() is fired. Example code:

```
boolean isControlPressed=false;


void keyPressed(){
  if(key==CODED && keyCode==CONTROL)isControllPressed=true;
  else if(key == 'c' || key == 'C'){
    if(isControlPressed){
      //do control-c stuff
    }
  }
}

void keyReleased(){
  if(key==CODED && keyCode==CONTROL)isControllPressed=false;
}
```

edit: me not checking for the key being CODED when checking if it is c is bad practice, don't emulate that, I was typing quick.

Also I think there is a function run when the application is closed you could use to quick save data if that is a problem

Comment: Did you try recording `Apple-Key` + `Alt-key` + `Esc-key` on the mac as asked? As the problem is that the `Esc-key` does not arrive at keyPressed function.

Comment: The `Esc-key` is not a system short-cut